# Fixing hidden recovery partitions that use UEFI

Tags: uefi, reset, refresh

Many name brand Windows 8 computers now use UEFI and have partitions to allow for refresh and reset of Windows.  Many of which I have had issues with the reset / refresh / and troubleshooting options disappear from advance menu.  How can these be repaired or re-linked so a factory restore can be done or diagnostics ran? I have used diskpart to set the system partition to get Windows booted when a MBR is corrupt, but fixing the hidden partitions isn't the same. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this yet-> https://www.storagecraft.com/support/kb/article/297 are you still trying to recover data off the drives or are you just trying to get them working?

1) set bios to legacy or compatibility mode(make sure to change this back after recovery)
2) once booted into the recovery environment right click the disk and select "convert to GPT disk"
-if "convert to MBR disk" is the only option do that then change back to GPT
3) The Disk Signature window will show after the disk is converted to GPT format.
4) Select OK to set the defautls when creating a system disk.
5) Once the Recovery env configures the disk as GPT there will be three partitions -system -UEFI -the partition for the OS restore
6) The space will not be allocated to the partition. To do this create partiton size that is the same size or larger than the OS being restored.
7) The only option will be different in UEFI\GPT restore is for the MBR and track Zero options. -not what we are doing so they are grayed out
8) If this restore is to different hardware from the backup, select to use the "Hardware Independent Restore" option.
9) Once the restore is done, verify, with the "Boot Configureation Utility" tool, that the machine reports as bootable.
-If the boot is broken, then select the auto repair step to correctly configure the machine to boot.

10) if you changed your bios to boot off the recovery env change it back.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: noted thank you, ill go through and edit the answer